# Why 2 XOR 3 is 1 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xor

All:

There is one algorithm question: add integer a and b without using + and -.
I try to use XOR to do that, but when I use 2^3 the result become 1, I guess my understanding about ^ is wrong, so anyway I wonder how can I get 5?

Thanks

Comment: You can't just directly substitute another operator for `+` and expect the same result - if you could we wouldn't need `+`.

Answer (score 4):

```
  1 0 => 2
^ 1 1 => 3
= 0 1 => 1
```

XOR means either one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

that is the proper way that XOR works

1: 0001
2: 0010
3: 0011

0010 ^ 0011 combines the 1s where there is only 1.  any position where there are 1s in both sets turns into a 0.  Therefore, 2 ^ 3 == 1.

Here is a solution to the brain teaser question of adding without using +

https://helloacm.com/how-to-compute-sum-of-two-integers-without-plus-and-minus-operators/

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, `a ^= b` was actually a pretty good start, but you'll need a little more code to transform it into an 'add'.

```js
function addIntegers(a, b) {
  var c;
  
  while(b) {   // while we have something to add ...
    c = a & b; // c = bits that are set in both a and b
    c <<= 1;   // shift it by 1 position to the left to get the carries of addition
    a ^= b;    // here you go! 0+0 = 0^0, 0+1 = 0^1, 1+0 = 1^0, 1+1 = 1^1 + missing carry
    b = c;     // restart with missing carries
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(addIntegers(123, 456));
```